# I am getting error during URL parsing. any suggestion

Tags: python, django

I want to create a django app in which by entering the URL of any website it will return with images of that website.

'module' object has no attribute 'parse'

This is my error.

This is my views.py of my application

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib3
import urlparse3

def home(request):
template = loader.get_template('home.html')
c = {}
h = {}
z = []
if request.POST:
url = request.POST["url"]
r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
c = tree.xpath('//img/@src')
h = tree.xpath('//a/@href')
for x in c:
    if bool(urllib3.parse.urlparse3(x).netloc):
        z.append(x)
    else:
        z.append(str(url) + str(x))

 return render_to_response("home.html", {'h': h, 'z' : z},   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But it return with errors when i entered URL for getting images.

Comment: What error are you receiving though? Please update your question.

Comment: I am getting... 'module' object is not callable...

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: i have changed it to urlparse3.parse_url(x).netlock ...Now it returns with a error message "name "basestring "is not defined"....

Comment: What is `urlparse3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `urlparse3.urlparse3`, if you read the documentation carefully you should be calling `urlparse3.parse_url` instead.

Comment: i have changed it to urlparse3.parse_url(x).netlock    ...Now it returns with a error message "name "basestring "is not defined"....

Comment: @tanmoysarkar You must be using Python 3, while `urlparse3` is Python 2 only.

Comment: but i installed urlparse3... so what i supposed to do for that.

Comment: this what i getting now.. 'module' object has no attribute 'parse_url'

Comment: @tanmoysarkar You can install `urlparse3` in Python 3, but it would be unusable, so you are supposed to find an alternative. You can try `urllib.parse.urlparse`

Comment: I have installed urllib3 also... please help me to solve this i am in very early stage of python. now it returns with 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'.....

Comment: @tanmoysarkar You should first check which version you are using with `python --version`

Comment: thank you this problem has resolved...thank you,,,,,